# What does inverse_of do in Rails belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

First, I know how inverse_of works in has_many association.

```
# relationship without inverse_of
user has_many :orders

# this will generate two database queries
user.orders.first.user
Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`user_id` = 2  ORDER BY `orders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
```

Here, user and user.order.first.user are two different object.

And with inverse_of

```
# relationship with inverse_of
user has_many :orders, inverse_of: :user

# this will generate just one database query
user.orders.first.user
Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`user_id` = 2  ORDER BY `orders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Now, user and user.order.first.user are the same object.

But, what inverse_of does in this belongs_to associstaion?

```
# relationship with inverse_of in belongs_to association
order belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :orders

order.user.orders
# will generate two database queries
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`user_id` = 2
```

There are no difference if I use inverse_of or not use inverse_of in this relationship. So, maybe I use it in a wrong way? what's the point of inverse_of in belongs_to association?